# Form taking too much time when a very long base64 string is posted

Tags: php, string, apache, post, base64

Our PHP script is hosted on Linux based Apache Server. I have a form with one *textarea* and a *submit button*. This *textarea* contains a very long base64 string of *284312* characters.

When I submit this form it takes too much time. It is still processing after a very long time. It is working for small base64 string and images are posted successfully but it is not working with large size images base64 string.

I am using following code on server side to get this base64 image:

```
$ifp = fopen( "images/myimage.png", "wb" );
$status = fwrite( $ifp, base64_decode( str_replace(' ', '+', $_REQUEST['image'] ) ) );
fclose( $ifp );
```

Is there any solution for this? Should I change anything in my PHP or Apache configuration ?

Comment: First you say that it's slow and then that it's "not working". Which is it? What does "not working" mean? Why are you using `str_replace`? Isn't this a POST request?

Comment: No Idea. It is slow or not working.. because it is still processing after half hour. No result in the end when there is a very long base64 sring

Comment: Why are you using a textarea to submit images?

Comment: it is my test form to post base64 string.. actually I will use my server to get images posted in the form of base64 string from other clients..

Comment: @jeff: It is test form. I am getting images from .Net client in the form of base64 string. we are getting timeout error from .Net as well when there is large image.

Comment: call this at the top of the php file: set_time_limit(0); But it will surely slower the speed of the form as the text is too long.

Comment: Just tried your script on PHP 5.4.4-14, webserver nginx 1.2.1, image 5.6mb, base64 7489332 characters and works fine, without problems. Execution time: 0.099922895431519s. Looks like your php is outdated ?

Answer (score 1):

Try it without $_REQUEST, my complete script first, here is the code which works fine for me, if it does not work for you, then provide complete info about PHP/webserver/machine (os, cpu..):
But I think it is something about passing chars from your textarea to the code, I did not get it well how you do it, but testing script below gives us answers :)

```
<?php
    $time_start = microtime(true); 

    $imagedata = file_get_contents('Cat2.jpg'); //5616998 bytes
    $base64 = base64_encode($imagedata);

    //echo strlen($base64); //7489332 characters

    $ifp = fopen('myimage.png', 'wb');
    $status = fwrite($ifp, base64_decode(str_replace(' ', '+', $base64)));
    fclose($ifp);

    echo 'Total execution time in seconds: ' . (microtime(true) - $time_start); //0.098897218704224 seconds
?>
```

More posted in comments before.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am using *PHP 5.3.3* on server. I put this micro second thing in my code. But I am unable to view this time in the end because it is still working and no response.

Comment: Did you try whole php script? forget your .NET app or whatever you're using, just try this whole script pointing directly to image file and if it stucks, then the problem is in PHP settings / version. But I have almost default php settings.

Comment: OK. I used your code on server and same image is successfully uploaded. and my response is "Total execution time in seconds: 0.0044651031494141"

Comment: it means problem is with POSTing that base64 data. ??

Comment: Yes, you would have to provide more of your code, exactly how you use it, so I could test it and find the solution, looks like its not problem in php and not in what you want to do, but the problem is in how you're doing it.